# Complete Materials list

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to put together a mysql db with a web interface. This needs to show the complete make up of an item. For example: Item **A** is made from 5 component **B**, 10 component **C** and one component **D**. Component **B** is made of one sub-component **e**, one sub-component **f**, and 10 sub-component **g**. Component **C** is made of two sub-components: one each of **h** and **i**. Component **D** has no sub-components. When I enter a qty (on an html/php form) for Item **A**. I would like to have a complete break down of components and sub components. In this example, I need 10 **A**. My output should read something like:

B - 50 comprised of:

- e - 50
- f - 50
- g - 500

C - 100 comprised of:

- h - 100
- i - 100

D - 10

Can someone point me in the right direction to start SELECTing this out?

Comment: Do you already have tables? If so, what do they look like?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a material table that describes the name of your material and such. Then, I would have a join table that has a column for the parent material id and a column for the child material id along with the amount of the child material that is needed.

Example: Material A would have id 1, Material B id 2, Material C id 3, and Material D id 4. If your material A called for 1 part material B and 3 parts material C it would have entries in the join table saying [1 (A's id), 2 (b's id), 1 (# of parts)] and [1, 3, 3]. Now, lets say that if material B had 3 parts C and 4 parts D it would have the entries [2 (B's id), 3 (c's id), 3 (parsts)] and [2, 4 (d's id), 4 (parts]. Pulling this out you would start at the root (A), ask the join table for all entries with the parent id = A's id and then do the same thing with each child material id (ask the table for all entries with the child id as the parent material) and so on. It would have to be a recursive function unless you specified some sort of maximum depth

The potential problem is that if you make material A depend on B, and B depends on A, you will have infinite recursion. You would have to do some serious error checking to make sure that none of the children references anything further up its tree so it doesn't loop around. Creating this error checking would probably be the hardest part of this implementation.

Your select statement would not be able to be executed all as one since SQL (as far as I know) doesn't really support recursion and so you would probably want to create a parameterized query like "SELECT * FROM TheJoinTable WHERE parentId=?" and just keep running it over and over again until you reach an end where the number of rows returned is 0. You will need to also make this function build on a nested array that you could easily then turn into your output for your page.

For parameterized querying, look into the PDO library for php. Parameterized querying will also solve many sql injection issues and it should be a general practice in my opinion.

I hope that wasn't too confusing...your question basically asked for an implementation and I find it difficult to keep implementation descriptions short and when I do try to keep them short I sometimes end up forgetting to mention something.